# git submodule update upstream

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a super project with a submodule in it (Overleaf project). I have made changes to the submodule but they are not showing up in the super project. I want to update the superproject to reflect the latest commits to the submodule. My understanding is that `git submodule update` acts on the submodule to fetch the latest commits from the super project but how do I do the reverse?

When in the superproject I run `git submodule update --remote` it tells me no changes found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to use the latest Git 2.31 or more, because [`git submodule` had some issues before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309), including when [fetching commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835815/6309).

Second, try and specify the [branch you want your submodule to track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)

```
cd /path/to/your/parent/repo
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

And make sure your submodule is actually at the latest of that branch:

```
cd path/to/your/submodule
git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch
# if the master branch already exist:
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Then try again:

- Make a new commit in an another cloned repository of Overleaf, and push it
- Try a `git submodule update --remote` in the super project.